# Windows Forms crashes while updating DataGridView in UI thread from worker thread while scrolling vertically continuesly

Tags: winforms, datagridview, thread-safety, real-time, vertical-scrolling

I have a Windows Forms App as a Client (in VB.NET) and I have a DataGridView where I want to see in real time changes that took place in a table in a database. I have another Windows Forms App as a Server that compares every 5 seconds old and new state and post to the client through WCF.
At the client side I read new data in a background worker thread (in order to have a responsive UI) and I run a loop inside the worker thread of new rows. Then when I try to update DataGridView table in the main thread using DataGridView1.Invoke method while scrolling continuesly the vertical scrollbar it throws the following exception.

```
at System.Collections.Hashtable.HashtableEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.JNSA.a(GridEXRow )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.a(Graphics , Boolean )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.a(Graphics )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.t()
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.set_FirstRow(Int32 value)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.OnScrollBarScroll(Int32 scrollCode)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.ScrollableBase.a(Object , ScrollEventArgs )
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.JNSBY.OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.JNSBY.a(Int32 , Int32 )
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Client.mdlMain.Main(String[] args)
```

Here is my code

```
Private Delegate Sub addrowcallback(table As DataTable, addedRow As DataRow)
Private Sub Add(table As DataTable, addedRow As DataRow)
                    If Me.IsHandleCreated Or GridControl1.IsHandleCreated Then
                        If (GridControl1.InvokeRequired Or Me.InvokeRequired) Then
                            Dim d As New addrowcallback(AddressOf Add)
                            Me.Invoke(d, table, addedRow)
                        Else
                            Dim gridHandle As IntPtr = GridControl1.Handle
                            GridControl1.Invoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                              table.ImportRow(addedRow)
                                                           End Sub))
                            Application.DoEvents()
                        End If
                    End If
End Sub
```

The exception is not happening when I stop WCF Service and I keep scrolling continuesly.

Important note!

- I have about 30.000 records and every 5 seconds I have to update about between 0 - 30. If I don't scroll I have no exception. The exception is only while scrolling and updating.

As you can see in my code I implement the following line in order to request specific handle of the control in the main thread:

```
Dim gridHandle As IntPtr = GridControl1.Handle
```

Comment: Don't `Invoke()` (not good for this in any case) from the BackGroundWorker's `DoWork` handler and, most of all, don't call `Application.DoEvents()` (bad in general, incredibly bad in this context). Use the `ReportProgress()` method to update the UI. -- Possibly, use a Task and a `Progress<T>` delegate for this.

Comment: + Not clear why you're try to invoke either the Form or the DGV: if you need to `Invoke()` something, use the Form in any case. Not sure what this line is meant to do: `Dim gridHandle As IntPtr = GridControl1.Handle`. Are you trying to create the Handle if it's not created yet? This also: `If Me.IsHandleCreated Or GridControl1.IsHandleCreated Then ...` is useless.